# Is Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate atomic?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I understand that the update functionality of `findOneAndUpdate` is atomic.

But is the returned result (when passing `new: true`) guaranteed to be the result of the immediate query?

For example, if I run the following, is the return value guaranteed to be `original kilometers + 1`, or could it be a greater number, if `kilometers` is incremented by another call?

`Car.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "123"}, {$inc: {kilometers: 1}}, { new: true }).then(car => console.log(car.kilometers)) // Is the return value guaranteed to be unique, regardless of how many simultaneous calls are made?`

I want to know because I'll be issuing a lot of these calls simultaneously, but the return value must be unique in each case.

If not, is there a way to atomically increment a record, and return the incremented value, so that the returned value is guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes:**

> ***Atomic Updates***
>
> With the exception of an unindexed upsert, findOneAndUpdate() is
> atomic. That means you can assume the document doesn't change between
> when MongoDB finds the document and when it updates the document,
> unless you're doing an upsert.
>
> For example, if you're using save() to update a document, the document
> can change in MongoDB in between when you load the document using
> findOne() and when you save the document using save() as show below.
> For many use cases, the save() race condition is a non-issue. But you
> can work around it with findOneAndUpdate() (or transactions) if you
> need to.

See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#atomic-updates